# Proving properties of real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $a, b, c$ are positive real numbers such that $abc = 1$, then which of the following is true?

$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \geq a + b + c$

or

$a ^2 + b^2 + c^2 > a + b + c$

How to find this out?

Answer (score 2):

$a=b=c=1$ satisfies both conditions $abc=1$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2 = a+b+c$.

So the second inequality is wrong

Comment: but what if a,b,c are not equal to 1?  say a=1, b=2, c=.5 @Angelo Mark

Comment: Then $abc \neq 1$.

Comment: if a=1, b=2 and c=1/2 then abc=1 isn't it? @Angelo Mark

Comment: Then $abc=1$. $1^2+2^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 > 1+2+\frac{1}{2}$. $\geq$ means "greater than or equal"

Answer (score 1):

By contrahamonic mean $\ge$ geometric mean:

\begin{align*}
  \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{a+b+c} & \ge \sqrt[3]{abc} \\
  &= 1 \\
\end{align*}